# Pandas: Pivot a DataFrame, columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame defined like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

table = OrderedDict((
    ('year', [1900, 1900, 1900, 1900, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901]),
    ('variable',['PRCP', 'PRCP', 'TAVG', 'TAVG', 'PRCP', 'PRCP', 'TAVG', 'TAVG']),
    ('month',  [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]),
    ('first_day',  [5, 8, 7, 3, 9, 2, 4, 1]),
    ('second_day',  [5, 8, 7, 3, 9, 2, 5, 8]),
    ('third_day',  [1, 7, 5, 7, 3, 5, 8, 9])
))
df = DataFrame(table)
```

The DataFrame is now this:

```
   year variable  month  first_day  second_day  third_day
0  1900     PRCP      1          5           5          1
1  1900     PRCP      2          8           8          7
2  1900     TAVG      1          7           7          5
3  1900     TAVG      2          3           3          7
4  1901     PRCP      1          9           9          3
5  1901     PRCP      2          2           2          5
6  1901     TAVG      1          4           5          8
7  1901     TAVG      2          1           8          9
```

I want to pivot the DataFrame so that it then looks like this:

```
   variable  year  month  day  value
0      PRCP  1900      1    1      5
1      PRCP  1900      1    2      5
2      PRCP  1900      1    3      1
3      PRCP  1900      2    1      8
4      PRCP  1900      2    2      8
5      PRCP  1900      2    3      7
6      PRCP  1901      1    1      7
7      PRCP  1901      1    2      7
8      PRCP  1901      1    3      5
9      PRCP  1901      2    1      3
10     PRCP  1901      2    2      3
11     PRCP  1901      2    3      7
12     TAVG  1900      1    1      9
13     TAVG  1900      1    2      9
14     TAVG  1900      1    3      3
15     TAVG  1900      2    1      2
16     TAVG  1900      2    2      2
17     TAVG  1900      2    3      5
18     TAVG  1901      1    1      4
19     TAVG  1901      1    2      5
20     TAVG  1901      1    3      8
21     TAVG  1901      2    1      1
22     TAVG  1901      2    2      8
23     TAVG  1901      2    3      9
```

I think I want to do this via pivoting, but I've not yet worked out how to do this using the `pivot()` or `pivot_table()`functions. How can I do this, with or without using a pivot?

Comment: You're looking for [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), but first `rename` columns by `dict`:

```
d = {'first_day':1,'second_day':2,'third_day':3}
df = pd.melt(df.rename(columns=d), id_vars=['variable','year','month'], var_name='day')
df = df.sort_values(['variable','year','month', 'day']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   variable  year  month day  value
0      PRCP  1900      1   1      5
1      PRCP  1900      1   2      5
2      PRCP  1900      1   3      1
3      PRCP  1900      2   1      8
4      PRCP  1900      2   2      8
5      PRCP  1900      2   3      7
6      PRCP  1901      1   1      9
7      PRCP  1901      1   2      9
8      PRCP  1901      1   3      3
9      PRCP  1901      2   1      2
10     PRCP  1901      2   2      2
11     PRCP  1901      2   3      5
12     TAVG  1900      1   1      7
13     TAVG  1900      1   2      7
14     TAVG  1900      1   3      5
15     TAVG  1900      2   1      3
16     TAVG  1900      2   2      3
17     TAVG  1900      2   3      7
18     TAVG  1901      1   1      4
19     TAVG  1901      1   2      5
20     TAVG  1901      1   3      8
21     TAVG  1901      2   1      1
22     TAVG  1901      2   2      8
23     TAVG  1901      2   3      9
```

Or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) column `day` by `dict`:

```
d = {'first_day':1,'second_day':2,'third_day':3}
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['variable','year','month'], var_name='day')
df.day = df.day.map(d)
df = df.sort_values(['variable','year','month', 'day']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   variable  year  month  day  value
0      PRCP  1900      1    1      5
1      PRCP  1900      1    2      5
2      PRCP  1900      1    3      1
3      PRCP  1900      2    1      8
4      PRCP  1900      2    2      8
5      PRCP  1900      2    3      7
6      PRCP  1901      1    1      9
7      PRCP  1901      1    2      9
8      PRCP  1901      1    3      3
9      PRCP  1901      2    1      2
10     PRCP  1901      2    2      2
11     PRCP  1901      2    3      5
12     TAVG  1900      1    1      7
13     TAVG  1900      1    2      7
14     TAVG  1900      1    3      5
15     TAVG  1900      2    1      3
16     TAVG  1900      2    2      3
17     TAVG  1900      2    3      7
18     TAVG  1901      1    1      4
19     TAVG  1901      1    2      5
20     TAVG  1901      1    3      8
21     TAVG  1901      2    1      1
22     TAVG  1901      2    2      8
23     TAVG  1901      2    3      9
```

Another solution with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
d = {'first_day':1,'second_day':2,'third_day':3}
df = df.rename(columns=d).set_index(['variable','year','month'])
       .stack()
       .reset_index(name='value')
       .rename(columns={'level_3':'day'})
print (df)
   variable  year  month  day  value
0      PRCP  1900      1    1      5
1      PRCP  1900      1    2      5
2      PRCP  1900      1    3      1
3      PRCP  1900      2    1      8
4      PRCP  1900      2    2      8
5      PRCP  1900      2    3      7
6      TAVG  1900      1    1      7
7      TAVG  1900      1    2      7
8      TAVG  1900      1    3      5
9      TAVG  1900      2    1      3
10     TAVG  1900      2    2      3
11     TAVG  1900      2    3      7
12     PRCP  1901      1    1      9
13     PRCP  1901      1    2      9
14     PRCP  1901      1    3      3
15     PRCP  1901      2    1      2
16     PRCP  1901      2    2      2
17     PRCP  1901      2    3      5
18     TAVG  1901      1    1      4
19     TAVG  1901      1    2      5
20     TAVG  1901      1    3      8
21     TAVG  1901      2    1      1
22     TAVG  1901      2    2      8
23     TAVG  1901      2    3      9
```